# How can one prevent baby/recently sprouted plant disease?

Tags: diseases, germination, fungus

When one desires to germinate seeds in the seedling tray, he/she has to keep a humid and warm environment. But this environment is also favored by fungus. Other than sterilizing the soil, how can one prevent fungus growth on baby plants?

Also if you sterilize the soil will you have the same germination rate?

Comment: A humid environment isn't strictly essential for many seedlings, whether or not they like it.

Answer (score 5):

**re: "How can one prevent baby/recently sprouted plant disease?"**
With knowledge & proper care.

**re:  "When one desires to germinate seeds in the seedling tray, he/she has to keep a humid and warm environment."**
Depending on the type/s of seeds that you are trying to germinate, you may not need a warm & humid environment.  Most garden seeds germinate fine at 68°F when planted in open soil (i.e. no cover required on top of the seed tray).  Just plant, water, & mist occasionally.  I never use seed tray covers & I never have problems with seed germination or disease caused by fungus or other undesirable factors that favor humid conditions.

**re:  "Other than sterilizing the soil, how can one prevent fungus growth on baby plants?"**
Start with good soil & then allow air to circulate around your seedlings (don't use a seed tray cover--it isn't necessary in most cases).

**re:  "Also if you sterilize the soil will you have the same germination rate?"**
Seeds germinate fine in sterile soil, however, beneficial microbes often help plants grow better due their symbiotic relationship to plant nutrient availability.

Comment: I don't have enough points to up this, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Seeds do not germinate fine in every form of sterilized soil. For instance, I baked some topsoil once to sterilize it, and germination rates were much lower in it afterward. Fresh seed-starting mix can be great stuff, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can help prevent fungal diseases by using a high quality seed raising mix in which to germinate your seeds.  It will have been either sterilized so that it will be free of fungal spores, or, will have beneficial fungi as such as Trichoderma added which encourages healthy soil conditions.  You can also add [Trichoderma harzianum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichoderma_harzianum) pellets or powders to your seed raising mix.

You only need to enclose your seedlings if the weather is too cold to germinate at room temperature, by creating a mini-glasshouse.

Comment: Terrarium-like conditions are also beneficial when the climate is very dry or watering frequency will be low--neither of which is likely the situation for the questioner--as s/he looks like a newbie who will likely over attend her/his plants.